# How do I rescue a multiple assignment in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

```
foo, bar = 1, 0/0 rescue 0, 0 # this won't work
foo.should eql 0
bar.should eql 0
```

How do I go about making this pass?

Comment: I don't think you mean `a` and `b` in the latter 2 lines...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foo, bar = ([1, 0/0] rescue [0, 0])
```